# "Entire Directory" option missing from Locations in "Select Users, Computers, SrvAct, or Groups" dialog

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, user-management

I'm a very inexperienced server admin, so if fail to provide some important information I apologize in advance. I am doing some development for a very small software company and I'm having a bit of an issue with accessing Active Directory users from one of the machines. They have 3 servers total - Server A is the Active Directory server, Servers B and C are both development servers and all of them are Windows Server 2008 R2.

When I attempt to manage security for users/computers on Server B I can see the "Entire Directory" in the list of locations when selecting users. On Server C, it is not present.

Both B and C are setup in Active Directory on A, but until an hour ago C was "disabled". I enabled C, and restarted B just for good measure. It didn't make a difference. Is there something I need to do on Server A to propagate that change? Was that my problem in the first place, or is there something else I need to do to allow Server C access the Active Directory listing.

Just as a specific example, let's say I want to add a domain user to the local Administrators group. From Server Manager -> Configuration -> Local Users and Groups -> Groups -> Administrators => "Add to Group...". I click "Add", then click the "Locations..." button. On Server B "Entire Directory" is listed and I can choose any user in Active Directory, on Server C it is not.

Any ideas? I'm happy to look up any relevant information that I've left out! Thanks in advance

Comment: `until an hour ago C was "disabled". I enabled C` - What do you mean by that? Are you logging onto server C with a domain account? Is server C correctly configured to use server A for DNS?

Comment: From the "Active Directory Users and Computers" tool, when listing all computers there is a context menu option on each computer: "Enable Account" (or "Disable Account"). Server C was the only server on the list that was disabled.

Comment: I log onto Server C with a local account. I'm not sure how to determine if C is correctly configured to use server A for DNS - but Server A is setup with the DNS server role and C is not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. The previous IT staff neglected to add Server C to the domain. I went to System and noticed the Domain was instead set to a Workgroup, so I added the server to the domain, rebooted C, and now I can login using a domain account and everything is where it should be. I suddenly have some issues with SQLServer on that box starting, but that's a different problem entirely